# PHP further process result of ImagePNG() without saving to disk?

Tags: php

Is there a way to process created image (using `ImagePNG()` from GD library) in memory *so to speak* without need to save temporary file to disk? What I am trying to achieve is basically to POST created image and would like to avoid any need to create temporary files, if possible. PHP would just output response of that POST from server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well then you need [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

From the docs:
PHP supports libcurl, a library created by Daniel Stenberg, that allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of servers with many different types of protocols. libcurl currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension), HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password authentication.

To capture the image in memory and send it with curl after you could try output buffering:

```
    <?php
ob_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
ImageJpg(...);
$myImage = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean ();

?>
```

Something like that?

Comment: Thanks, I know how to output it back to screen (to browser), but I need the created image to POST (upload to different server through form) and just output the response from that POST. Script will be running through PHP-CLI (cronjob) so there's no interaction with web browser.

Comment: @Andrew Edited my answer use curl.

Comment: Thanks again. I know how to use curl. The problem is not the POST itself, but how can I get the picture into variable to use with cURL without need to store it on disk. That is the code between `ImagePNG()` and `curl_init()` I don't know if I can describe it better than that.

Comment: @Andrew how about using output buffering (ob_start etc) to capture your output in a variable and then connect to the other server and serve it the file?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the output buffering but gave up after two hours. This is what worked for me:

First create a temporary file and then pass that to ImagePNG(). After that just use file reading routine to read the file content and store the result in a variable and delete the temp file created (unlink($tmp); )

```
$tmpfile = tempnam("/tmpdir", "img");
//your name will not clash with another request

imagepng($my_img,$tmpfile);
$handle = fopen($tmpfile, "rb");
$img_file_contents = fread($handle, filesize($tmpfile));
fclose($handle);
unlink($tmpfile); //no accumulation of image files
//now send the $img_file_contents via cURL
```